# sklearn pipeline issues with fitting

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
features = ['State', 'City', 'Trade', 'Year']
X = df[features]
y = df['Total']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=args['val_size'], random_state=args['random_seed'])
```

I wish to use `LabelEncoder` on `X` columns leaving out `Year` , `MinMaxScaler` on `Total` and finally `model=LinearRegression`How can I fit this as a sklearn pipeline ?

samle code

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx')

steps = [
    ('label_encoder', LabelEncoder()),
    ('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('model', na())
]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

features = ['State', 'City', 'Trade', 'Year']
X = df[features]
y = df['Total']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=args['val_size'], random_state=args['random_seed'])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error: unable to locate `Total` and the label encoder is not able to handle more than one column.

Comment: And maybe you can provide a sample and the code you have tried so far? You can also explain which issues you have, I don't see any issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) to specify on which columns to use the encoder. I don't think you can scale `y` in a pipeline, but you can just scale it outside the pipeline (usually you shouldn't scale `y`).
`LabelEncoder` is for a single column only, you can use [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) instead.
Here is the code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx')

features = ['State', 'City', 'Trade', 'Year']
features_cat = features.copy()
features_cat.remove('Year')

X = df[features]
y = df[['Total']]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=args['val_size'], random_state=args['random_seed'])

# Scaling the Target (not recomended)
target_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_train = target_scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = target_scaler.transform(y_test)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('Categorical features', OrdinalEncoder(), features_cat),
            ],
            remainder='passthrough')    # 'Year' column will be kept as it is

pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('preprocessor', preprocessor), 
                ('LinearRegression', LinearRegression()),
            ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```